# Is it possible to re-use `("0" | "1")` via a parameter entity in DTD?

Tags: xml, syntax, dtd

Some companies "throw out" XML with a lengthy wordy description of their tags, but never made any effort to formally describe the structure of such mess.
Thus I'm trying to build a DTD from such a description.

One thing is that `0` and `1` are used for Boolean values for several tags, so I tried to define `("0" | "1" )` as "parameter entity", but failed with various syntax errors.

My last attempt was:

```dtd
<!-- Boolean -->
<!ENTITY _false "0">
<!ENTITY _true "1">
<!ENTITY % BOOL "(&_false; | &_true;)">

<!-- Error -->
<!ELEMENT Error %BOOL;>
```

`xmllint` threw out errors like this:

```text
Entity: line 1: parser error : ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected
 %BOOL;
       ^
Entity: line 1:
(&_false; | &_true;)
 ^
Entity: line 1: parser error : expected '>'
 %BOOL;
       ^
```

Is it possible to use a parameter entity for that?
I tried to search for examples, but failed to find some.
Also my DTD practical experience is rather low.

### Another Variant

Experimenting I tried this instead:

```dtd
<!-- Boolean -->
<!ENTITY % BOOL '"0" | "1"'>

<!-- Error -->
<!ELEMENT Error (%BOOL;)>
```

Then `xmllint` threw out errors like this:

```text
Entity: line 1: parser error : ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected
 %BOOL;
       ^
Entity: line 1:
"0" | "1"
^
Entity: line 1: parser error : expected '>'
 %BOOL;
       ^
Entity: line 1:
"0" | "1"
^
Entity: line 1: parser error : Content error in the external subset
 %BOOL;
       ^
Entity: line 1:
"0" | "1"
^
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve in/with `<!ELEMENT Error %BOOL;>`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#elemdecls for some element declaration examples. Perhaps add some XML samples showing the type of element(s) you want to define with your DTD.

Comment: As said, "the structure" of that "XML soup" is practically non-existent. And the example shown is just a single element that can contain (according to the written documentation) either `0`, or `1`. There is another element named `Warning` that can also contain either `0`, or `1`. Thus I wanted to define some Boolean that I could use as "content model" so to say. More clear now?

Answer (score 0):

DTDs cannot constrain the content of text nodes, only of attribute nodes.

For what you are attempting, you should be using a more powerful schema technology, for example [XML Schema Definition (XSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)), [REgular LAnguage for XML Next Generation (RelaxNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG), or [Schematron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron).

Comment: Actually if I had designed that "tag soup" it would have been different: The content model I'm dealing with uses *no attributes at all*. Probably my problem was that I was working with regular expressions for too long. As it seems `xmllint` only supports RelaxNG in addition to DTD. Would you improve your answer converting each of your schema technologies with links pointing to the corresponding reference or home page?

Comment: No, I'm here to answer your questions, not to provide one-to-one training or to write your code for you.

Comment: I see; actually I had started to learn and write RELAX NG, but it's much harder than writing a SGML DTD. On my previous comment: I think it would have bee rather trivial for you to add the links. I'll try myself...